# Unable to install .NET Framework 3.5 to my XP machine

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework

I have an application that requires .NET 3.5, but I can't install it.  The installer quits saying "it has encoutered a problem during setup.

If I look at some of the error logs in the tmp directory I see.

> Error occurred while initializing fusion.

It seems that I have 2.0 SP1 installed.  Any ideas how I can get it to work?

I went through the temp directory and found these references to the error.  Any ideas?

> [04/17/12,18:55:09] Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a. MSI returned error code 1603
>   [04/17/12,18:55:27] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a is not installed.
>
> 04/19/12 19:08:48 DDSet_Status: Loading fusion.dll using LoadLibraryShim()
>   04/19/12 19:08:48 DDSet_Error: Error occurred while initializing fusion. Setup could not load fusion with LoadLibraryShim(). Error: 0x80131700
>
> 04/19/12 19:08:48 DDSet_Status: Loading fusion.dll using LoadLibraryShim()
>   04/19/12 19:08:48 DDSet_Error: Error occurred while initializing fusion. Setup could not load fusion with LoadLibraryShim(). Error: 0x80131700
>   MSI (s) (74!08) [19:08:48:062]: Product: Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1 -- Error 25007.Error occurred while initializing fusion. Setup could not load fusion with LoadLibraryShim(). Error: 0x80131700
>   Error 25007.Error occurred while initializing fusion. Setup could not load fusion with LoadLibraryShim(). Error: 0x80131700

Comment: Look in your %temp% folder for the .NET setup log, and try to find the same error message in there. Look for error numbers etc. and either comment or update your question with that information, please. Fusion refers to the setup engine if I recall correctly.

Comment: Question updated with more error text.

Answer (score 2):

Install Windows Installer 3.1 first before install Net 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 0):

a.     Open the following location on the computer:

> %windir%\WinSxS

b.     Delete the “Policies” folder.

Reinstall .NET Framework and see if that does the trick.

Comment: This didn't work.  Same error.

Comment: Found this which has a modification to Anil's answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2010/07/12/quot-25007-error-occurred-while-initializing-fusion-setup-could-not-load-fusion-with-loadlibraryshim-error-the-handle-is-invalid-quot.aspx - try the batch file they want you to create there.